# Always getting RateLimitError in Pinecone

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, openai-api, langchain, vector-database

I have been trying for a long time. I have shifted to smaller documents (thinking that I was feeding way too many documents) and now I am just trying to embed 60 documents into my Pinecone index.

```
docsearch = Pinecone.from_texts([t.page_content for t in texts], embeddings, index_name=index_name
```

This is not working. What else should I try to bypass the rate limit error?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the free plan of OpenAI then it only allows 3 requests per minute.

You need to update to Pay as you go, which allows way more requests per minute.

Note that it's not related to ChatGPT plan. It's about the API plan.